# android prevent immediate trigger of alarm service if alarm time has passed for the day

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

The reference for Alarm Manager says that

> If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered
>   immediately.

I am facing this problem in my application. Here is my alarm manager code :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DinnerAlarmReceiver.class);
                pendingDinnerIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, myIntent, 0);

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingDinnerIntent);
```

Is there any workaround to this problem?

**-----EDIT------**

I have written some code to estimate if the set time for the alarm is before the current time . Here is the above portion with corresponding changes :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                long currentTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                long setTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                Timestamp setTimestamp = new Timestamp(setTime);
                Timestamp currentTimestamp = new Timestamp(currentTime);
                if (setTimestamp.after(currentTimestamp))
                {
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingDinnerIntent);
                }
                else
                {
                }
```

What should I the `alarmManager` to in case `setTimestamp` is before `currentTimestamp` ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't need to create `Timestamp`s. You can do it with your `Calendar`.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

if(calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingDinnerIntent);
```

I would also mention that as of KitKat, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 19 or above, the `AlarmManager#set()` method is not exact. If you want your alarm to fire at an exact time, you'll need to use a `setExact*()` method.

Comment: setExact() wont work for Repeating alarm.

Comment: Right, 'cause it's not a repeating alarm. All alarms figure the start times the same way, though, depending on the chosen clock.