# Multiple alarm triggered at once and not triggered at particular time

Tags: android, time, alarm

I build simple multiple alarm application in Android, but my alarm ringing at the same time. I think there is something wrong at millis conversion but I didn't get it what is going on here. Before I try to run single alarm and it works fine, I read some reference from similar question SO, I found if time millis are before current time the alarm run immediately, does my code look have same problem or another time converting issues? thanks

```
...
    private static AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private static ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray;

    public static int bellHour = 0;
    public static int bellMinute = 0;

    public static int arriveHour = 0;
    public static int arriveMinute = 0;

    public static int homeworkHour = 0;
    public static int homeworkMinute = 0;

    public static int wakeupHour = 0;
    public static int wakeupMinute = 0;

    public static int prayHour = 0;
    public static int prayMinute = 0;

    public static int workoutHour = 0;
    public static int workoutMinute = 0;

    public static int showerHour = 0;
    public static int showerMinute = 0;

    public static int breakfastHour = 0;
    public static int breakfastMinute = 0;

    public static int schoolHour = 0;
    public static int schoolMinute = 0;
...


public static void updateAlarmClock(Context context) {
...
// set variables hour and minute from sqlite
...
setupAlarm(context)
}
private static void setupAlarm(Context context) {
        cancelAlarms();

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        intentArray = new ArrayList<>();

        ScheduleRepository scheduleRepository = new ScheduleRepository(context);
        List<Schedule> schedules = scheduleRepository.retrieve();

        for (int i = 0; i < schedules.size(); i++) {
            Schedule schedule = schedules.get(i);
            Intent receiverIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            receiverIntent.putExtra(Schedule.ID, schedule.getId());
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, schedule.getId(), receiverIntent, 0);
            intentArray.add(pendingIntent);
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, getMillisTime(schedule), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

            Log.i("Schedule Alarm", "Alarm " + schedule.getLabel() + " ID " + String.valueOf(schedule.getId()));
        }
    }

public static void cancelAlarms() {
        if (alarmManager != null && intentArray != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < intentArray.size(); i++) {
                alarmManager.cancel(intentArray.get(i));
            }
        }
        if (AlarmReceiver.mp != null) {
            AlarmReceiver.mp.stop();
        }
    }

private static long getMillisTime(Schedule schedule) {
        int timeHour = 0;
        int timeMinute = 0;
        switch (schedule.getLabel()) {
            case Constant.ACT_HOMEWORK:
            timeHour = AlarmClock.homeworkHour;
            timeMinute = AlarmClock.homeworkMinute;
            Log.i("Schedule homework", timeHour + ":" + timeMinute);
            break;
        case Constant.ACT_WAKEUP:
            timeHour = AlarmClock.wakeupHour;
            timeMinute = AlarmClock.wakeupMinute;
            Log.i("Schedule sleep", timeHour + ":" + timeMinute);
            break;
        case Constant.ACT_PRAY:
            timeHour = AlarmClock.prayHour;
            timeMinute = AlarmClock.prayMinute;
            Log.i("Schedule pray", timeHour + ":" + timeMinute);
            break;
        case Constant.ACT_WORKOUT:
            timeHour = AlarmClock.workoutHour;
            timeMinute = AlarmClock.workoutMinute;
            Log.i("Schedule workout", timeHour + ":" + timeMinute);
            break;
        case Constant.ACT_SHOWER:
            timeHour = AlarmClock.showerHour;
            timeMinute = AlarmClock.showerMinute;
            Log.i("Schedule shower", timeHour + ":" + timeMinute);
            break;
        case Constant.ACT_BREAKFAST:
            timeHour = AlarmClock.breakfastHour;
            timeMinute = AlarmClock.breakfastMinute;
            Log.i("Schedule breakfast", timeHour + ":" + timeMinute);
            break;
        case Constant.ACT_SCHOOL:
            timeHour = AlarmClock.schoolHour;
            timeMinute = AlarmClock.schoolMinute;
            Log.i("Schedule school", timeHour + ":" + timeMinute);
            break;
        }

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timeHour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timeMinute);

        return  calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }
```

output of log the time each alarm in hour and minute

```
Schedule homework: 23:8
Schedule sleep: 0:8
Schedule pray: 5:18
Schedule workout: 5:28
Schedule shower: 5:43
Schedule breakfast: 5:58
Schedule school: 6:20
```

Comment: What do your log prints say the values for `timeHour` and `timeMinute` are? It doesn't look like you're ever setting values for, e.g., `homeworkHour` and `homeworkMinute`. Also, are you accounting for the possibility that the time you're setting has already passed for the day?

Comment: the hours and minutes are global variable that set before alarm start.

Comment: OK. Then what do you mean to do if a time has already passed today? That is, if this code runs at 06:00, is "pray" to be scheduled for tomorrow?

Comment: yes, I want alarm set such that way,,,and repeat everyday at the time, until it reset by user and cancel all alarm then set new again.

Comment: You'll need to compare the `calendar` to the current time, and add a day if it's already passed. Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535575/android-prevent-immediate-trigger-of-alarm-service-if-alarm-time-has-passed-for).

Comment: ok I will add the time comparator, is my alarm setter is good?, I mean it would produce potential error `alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, getMillisTime(schedule), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);` correspond the time setting maybe?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of error you're concerned about, but that's a valid, correct call to set a repeating, daily alarm based on the "wall clock", which sounds exactly like what you want.

Comment: @Mike It's work, thanks, if you mind to rewrite at the answer column, I will vote you up and checked as correct answer.

Comment: It's cool. You can just select the "That solved my problem!" button, if it's still there, to close out your question. Thank you, though. Glad you got it working. Cheers!