# Working out time from now until midnight in AlarmManager triggerAtMillis

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I want to create an alarm which will **first** fire at the **next** midnight and then repeat every midnight after.

Tried to calculate the time from now until midnight (in milliseconds) for the **triggeratMillis** parameter in the **setRepeating()** method *(so the first alarm fires at the next midnight)* but it is firing instantly as soon as it is created.

```
    private void resetAtMidnight() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MidnightReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
            MIDNIGHT_ALARM_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.getTimeInMillis()-System.currentTimeMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
            pendingIntent);
}
```

I tried to make a calendar object initially set to the current dates midnight and then subtract the current time (in milliseconds) from the calendar midnight time.

Then I thought it might be thinking the midnight specified was the previous midnight so I tried to make it 11:59pm on the current day but this also did not work and the alarm fired instantly anyway.

Comment: The `triggerAtMillis` parameter is the actual time to fire the first alarm, not the interval until then. Set your `Calendar` appropriately, and pass just `calendar.getTimeInMillis()`. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36535575) will likely be of some help to you, as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static long gettingNextMidnightTimeinMilliseconds() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return c.getTimeInMillis() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L);
}
```

Comment: instead of using  calendar.getTimeInMillis() use gettingNextMidnightTimeinMilliseconds