# AlarmManager triggers too fast

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager, receiver

I was trying to setup AlarmManager in my application but I am not sure if I am doing everything how it should be.

What I want to achieve is to have an alaram which gets setup once after installation of application and re-setup after every re-boot.

I think I am close but now just after loading application on emulator, alarm goes off and gives "Successully triggered" message although clock is set to 11 AM, not 9 AM...

It might be an issue with for..else condition in my Receiver but I am not sure, here is my code:

App.kt

```
class App : Application() {

override fun onCreate() {

    CheckExpiryAlarmReceiver.AlarmReceiver.setExpiryAlarmMonitor(applicationContext)

    super.onCreate()
}
}
```

CheckExpiryAlarmReceiver.kt

```
private const val REQUEST_CODE = 0
private const val ALARM_HOUR = 9

class CheckExpiryAlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

object AlarmReceiver {

    fun setExpiryAlarmMonitor(context: Context?) {

        val alarmMgr: AlarmManager = context?.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

        val alarmIntent: PendingIntent

        val mIntent = Intent(context, CheckExpiryAlarmReceiver::class.java)

        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, mIntent, 0)

        // Set the alarm to start at 9:00 AM
        val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

        calendar.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, ALARM_HOUR)

        // Every once a day
        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent)
    }
}

override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

    // Check if triggered by system re-boot
    if(intent?.action == "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED") {

       AlarmReceiver.setExpiryAlarmMonitor(context)

    } else { // Action to be actually performed by Alarm receiver

        Log.i("AlarmMonitor", "Triggered successfully!")

    }
}

}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks for all help! :)

Comment: What does your AndroidManifest look like?  You are probably not filtering your broadcast receiver intent correctly.

Comment: @slackwars here it is:

`<receiver
            android:name=".CheckExpiryAlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

Comment: You're not accounting for the possibility that the alarm time has already passed today. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535575