# Android alarm clock app going off when its not supposed to

Tags: java, android, android-studio, alarmmanager, timepicker

I am currently struggling to find why my alarm sometimes works as intended and other times does not.
It normally works when i set the alarm for a few minutes but when i set the alarm from say 10pm to 6am that's when it normally starts going off within about 10 seconds. Whenever i set the alarm from pm to am or vice versa the error occurs and the alarm just goes off.

I know its a lot of code but I'm pretty much desperate at this point.
Any help will be appreciated.

**Manifest**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.insomniafinal">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Register" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
        <receiver android:name=".Alarm_Receiver" />

        <service android:name=".RingtonePlayingService"
            android:enabled="true">
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Alarm Receiver**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class Alarm_Receiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // fetch extra strings from the intent
        // tells the app whether the user pressed the alarm on button or the alarm off button
        String get_your_string = intent.getExtras().getString("extra");

        // fetch the extra longs from the intent
        // tells the app which value the user picked from the drop down menu/spinner
        Integer get_your_whale_choice = intent.getExtras().getInt("whale_choice");

        // create an intent to the ringtone service
        Intent service_intent = new Intent(context, RingtonePlayingService.class);


        // pass the extra string from Receiver to the Ringtone Playing Service
        service_intent.putExtra("extra", get_your_string);
        // pass the extra integer from the Receiver to the Ringtone Playing Service
        service_intent.putExtra("whale_choice", get_your_whale_choice);

        // start the ringtone service
        context.startService(service_intent);

    }

}
```

**RingtonePlayingService**

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Random;

public class RingtonePlayingService extends Service {

    MediaPlayer media_song;
    int startId;
    boolean isRunning;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // fetch the extra string from the alarm on/alarm off values
        String state = intent.getExtras().getString("extra");
        // fetch the whale choice integer values
        Integer whale_sound_choice = intent.getExtras().getInt("whale_choice");

        // notification
        // set up the notification service
        NotificationManager notify_manager = (NotificationManager)
                getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // set up an intent that goes to the Main Activity
        Intent intent_main_activity = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        // set up a pending intent
        PendingIntent pending_intent_main_activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                intent_main_activity, 0);

        // make the notification parameters
        Notification notification_popup = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("An alarm is going off!")
                .setContentText("Click me!")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_call)
                .setContentIntent(pending_intent_main_activity)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();




        // this converts the extra strings from the intent
        // to start IDs, values 0 or 1
        assert state != null;
        switch (state) {
            case "alarm on":
                startId = 1;
                break;
            case "alarm off":
                startId = 0;
                Log.e("Start ID is ", state);
                break;
            default:
                startId = 0;
                break;
        }


        // if else statements

        // if there is no music playing, and the user pressed "alarm on"
        // music should start playing
        if (!this.isRunning && startId == 1) {
            Log.e("there is no music, ", "and you want start");

            this.isRunning = true;
            this.startId = 0;

            // set up the start command for the notification
            notify_manager.notify(0, notification_popup);

else if (this.isRunning && startId == 0) {
            Log.e("there is music, ", "and you want end");

            // stop the ringtone
            media_song.stop();
            media_song.reset();

            this.isRunning = false;
            this.startId = 0;
        }

        // these are if the user presses random buttons
        // just to bug-proof the app
        // if there is no music playing, and the user pressed "alarm off"
        // do nothing
        else if (!this.isRunning && startId == 0) {
            Log.e("there is no music, ", "and you want end");

            this.isRunning = false;
            this.startId = 0;

        }

        // if there is music playing and the user pressed "alarm on"
        // do nothing
        else if (this.isRunning && startId == 1) {
            Log.e("there is music, ", "and you want start");

            this.isRunning = true;
            this.startId = 1;

        }

        // can't think of anything else, just to catch the odd event
        else {
            Log.e("else ", "somehow you reached this");

        }



        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Tell the user we stopped.
        Log.e("on Destroy called", "ta da");

        super.onDestroy();
        this.isRunning = false;
    }
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

AlarmManager alarm_manager;
TimePicker alarm_timepicker;
TextView update_text;
Context context;
PendingIntent pending_intent;
int choose_whale_sound;
long startTime = 0;
long start = 0;
float numberOfHours = 0;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        this.context = this;


}alarm_manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        //initialize our timepicker
        alarm_timepicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

        //initialize our text update box
        update_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.update_text);

        // create an instance of a calendar
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        // create an intent to the Alarm Receiver class
        final Intent my_intent = new Intent(this.context, Alarm_Receiver.class);


        // create the spinner in the main UI
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.richard_spinner);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.whale_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Set an onclick listener to the onItemSelected method
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        // initialize start button
        Button alarm_on = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alarm_on);

        // create an onClick listener to start the alarm
        alarm_on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // setting calendar instance with the hour and minute that we picked
                // on the time picker
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarm_timepicker.getHour());
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarm_timepicker.getMinute());

                // get the int values of the hour and minute
                int hour = alarm_timepicker.getHour();
                int minute = alarm_timepicker.getMinute();

                // convert the int values to strings
                String hour_string = String.valueOf(hour);
                String minute_string = String.valueOf(minute);

                // convert 24-hour time to 12-hour time
                if (hour > 12) {
                    hour_string = String.valueOf(hour - 12);
                }

                if (minute < 10) {
                    //10:7 --> 10:07
                    minute_string = "0" + String.valueOf(minute);
                }

                // method that changes the update text Textbox
                set_alarm_text("Alarm set to: " + hour_string + ":" + minute_string);

                // put in extra string into my_intent
                // tells the clock that you pressed the "alarm on" button
                my_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm on");

                // put in an extra int into my_intent
                // tells the clock that you want a certain value from the drop-down menu/spinner
                my_intent.putExtra("whale_choice", choose_whale_sound);
                Log.e("The whale id is" , String.valueOf(choose_whale_sound));

                // create a pending intent that delays the intent
                // until the specified calendar time
                pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,
                        my_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                // set the alarm manager
                alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                        pending_intent);

                start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            }



        });



        // initialize the stop button
        Button alarm_off = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alarm_off);
        // create an onClick listener to stop the alarm or undo an alarm set

        alarm_off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // method that changes the update text Textbox
                set_alarm_text("Alarm off!");

                // cancel the alarm
                alarm_manager.cancel(pending_intent);

                // put extra string into my_intent
                // tells the clock that you pressed the "alarm off" button
                my_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm off");
                // also put an extra int into the alarm off section
                // to prevent crashes in a Null Pointer Exception
                my_intent.putExtra("whale_choice", choose_whale_sound);

                //Get duration of the alarm.
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long delta = end - start;
                int elapsedSeconds = (int)delta / 1000;
                int mins = elapsedSeconds/60;
                float hours = mins/60;

                documentReference.update("sleep", FieldValue.arrayUnion(hours));


                // stop the ringtone
                sendBroadcast(my_intent);



            }
        });



    }

    private void set_alarm_text(String output) {
        update_text.setText(output);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)

        // outputting whatever id the user has selected
        //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "the spinner item is "
        //        + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        choose_whale_sound = (int) id;


    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback

    }
```

Comment: You're not accounting for the possibility that the time you're setting the alarm for has already passed today. When you set an alarm for a time in the past, it will fire as soon as possible. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36536228.

Comment: As you say, it’s a lot of code. Please train [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Mike M your suggestion has solved my problem! You are correct and the alarm clock works as intended now thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question :)